# Navigationbar covers Vierpager content

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar, overlap

I have a tab layout and each tab is represented my a fragment in the viewpager. Now I tried to attach a Toolbar to the bottom but the android navigation bar keeps overlapping it. Adding a margin is not a option because it looks very strange on devices without a navigation bar on the screen.

[image: Screenshot from Android emulator]

XML from main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fragment_map_title" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fragment_list_title" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

XML from fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/ballon_info_bar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:background="#2a3b4c"
        android:id="@+id/ballon_info_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Style XML:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

I found several other posts about this topic but none of them solved my problem.

**EDIT1:** The margin in the image is just for visualization. 
**EDIT2:** According to the blueprint, the ViewPager is alredy behind the navigationbar

Comment: I think the problem is fitsSystemWindows, which tell Android to draw also under navigation bar and status bar

Comment: I tried to change fitSystemWindows for the ViewPager. It only removes the margin I added for demo purpose.

Comment: Can you post your style.xml?

Comment: Sure. Added it. And according to the blueprint its the Viewpager which is already behind the actionbar.

Comment: Try setting `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` to `false` and add this line to your style.xml `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>`

Comment: Adding android:fitsSystemWindows="false" to the ViewPager and setiing android:windowTranslucentNavigation to false was already enough. Tank you ver much!!

Comment: Perfect! In order to help others with this problem i will put that as an answer. So please mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

Setting `android:fitsSystemWindows` to `false` and setting `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` to `false` in `style.xml`